# TCS community on Google Plus

Tags: discussion

This is more an announcement than a question. There's a new TCS "community" on G+ that some of you might be interested in participating in. Moderators have to "approve" membership, but there's no particular filtering.

[Here's the community](https://plus.google.com/u/0/communities/102658328974323340942).

Comment: I suggest adding the [meta-tag:featured] tag to the post.